# Django test database looks empty while test is running

Tags: database, django, testing

I have a Django project that uses local PostgreSQL server.
I'm using a debugger to debug some weird bugs that I have. While the debugger is stopped on one of the tests, I tried to look at the test database. I see this new database (test_project1) and all the schemes are defined as they should be. But all tables are empty.

I know that the tables are not empty:

- I used a fixture and some tests already ran and returned data.
- A post test created a new user and returned 201 status code.

And yet, I see no data when I try to access the database with `pgAdmin3` or `psql`.

Any idea what is going on here?
Is there some kind of sophisticated cache mechanism that Django uses?

Answer (score 21):

Django's `TestCase` is [wrapping every test in its own transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#testcase). So your database is not being used any time you do a request through ORM.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to make sure that I'm not loosing it... :-)

Comment: If you want to disable the transaction you can temporarily inherit from TransactionTestCase rather than TestCase. It's a bit confusing: TestCase inherits from TransactionTestCase, but "but surrounds every test with a transaction, monkey-patches the real transaction management routines to do nothing...". This does work though, and is very useful for debugging. Yes, I had the same, "am I losing it?" moment. The reason you would want to use TestCase rather than TransactionTestCase, is that rolling back a transaction is faster than truncating tables.

Answer (score 3):

The database transaction that is being used by `django.test.TestCase` can be avoided by inheriting from `django.test.TransactionTestCase` instead of `TestCase`.  Then the data will be visible in the database.

You might want to just do this temporarily while debugging, so that you get the performance benefits of `django.test.TestCase` the rest of the time.

Django docs:
[django.test.TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase)
[django.test.TestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#testcase)