# Django server side cursor is not working in test

Tags: python-3.x, django, psycopg2

```
    with psycopg2.connect(conn_url) as conn:
        with conn.cursor(name=f"{uuid4()}") as cursor:
            cursor.itersize = batch_size
            cursor.execute(raw_sql, params)
```

this is returning empty row in django test.
But running correctly in shell_plus.

Also I have set @override_settings(DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS=False) .
But still getting the same result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django test database looks empty while test is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367338/django-test-database-looks-empty-while-test-is-running)